# Redirection failed to another server using .htaccess file

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have both Windows & Linux Servers.(Domain manage in Linux Server ).

My Domain is 
http://test.mydomain.com

Need to redirect to

http://192.97.XX.XX/Hello

I need All request that comes to http://test.mydomain.com Redirect it to http://192.97.XX.XX/Hello

Here i tried using htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test.mydomain\.com$
    RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/192.97.XX.XX\Hello \/"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will fail, because you are telling htaccess to look for `www.test.mydomain.com`, in addition to that, you're not escaping the `.` before `test`

If you change to this, you should be OK

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://192.97.XX.XX/Hello [R=301,L]
```

This now says:

- when the host starts with (that's what the `^` means) test.mydomain.com
- redirect it to http://192.97.XX.XX/Hello, and make it a permanent redirect (the 301 part, so Google etc can update their indexes)

**NB** I've also changed the last line considerably

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in document root of test domain:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?test\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://192.97.XX.XX/Hello/$1 [L,R]
```